# CC Data-dump: Are images included?

Tags: support, images, data-dump

I am wondering whether images that are embedded into posts are included in the cc data dumps? If so, how?

Comment: I guess they only include the links... all the images are hosted on imgur

Comment: Oh i see now. `<img>` tags to imgur. Perfect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the images are not included as Stack Exchange isn't hosting those images themselves, they rely on third-party services.

Images that are embedded in the markdown of a post with the Image uploader provided in the post editor will be sent to Stack Exchanges own domain on  i.stack.imgur.com to guarantee that those images don't get removed. Users are not required to use that feature though. They can simply link to any image source they like. Our browsers take charge of downloading those external resources.

Once you obtained the content of the Posts table you should run a script to parse and download the images yourself, similar to what your browser does.

Answer (score -2):

> Data-dump: Are images included?

No but they can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/Stack-Exchange-Image-Dataset).

Comment: I recommend linking to [the archive.org-hosted version](https://archive.org/details/stack-exchange-images) rather than GitHub, seeing as that's where you've actually hosted your dump. Do you have stats of how many / which images are missing from this dump?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The dataset contains all images hosted on i.stack.imgur.com that are linked to in the posts, post histories and comments from the Stack Exchange Data Dump dated 2023-12-08. I posted a link to git as it contains the documentation and I may add future images in another archive.org archive.

Comment: That would make this a link-only answer, and liable to be deleted.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 same if that was a link to archive.org

Comment: No, because that's the actual answer: “you can download it here”. Currently, you're saying “you can look at this other website, which tells you where you can download it”. If the GitHub page dies, the answer becomes unusable, but if the archive.org page dies, the answer becomes _incorrect_.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The GitHub page contains more info, including the answer to your first comment.

Comment: If you think it is relevant, include that info in this answer. See [Shog9's famous post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/308065) for more information. (Btw, my question was asking whether you had _stats_ about the missing images; I knew your methodology when I asked it.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I don't want to duplicate content. If someone wants the dataset, they'll go to GitHub where they'll find documentation, stats, license, download links, etc. Proving only download links as you suggest doesn't strike me as a better answer.