# Flagged "not an answer", flag marked helpful but answer still exists

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, flags, moderation

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829131/actionbar-items-appear-always-in-overflow-menu/22829310#22829310), which was marked as helpful. So why does this post still exist?

Someone edited the post a few minutes back, so here's the original revision that I flagged:

> Could you try with **android:showAsAction="always"** for the items in the menu.

I think this should be a comment.

If you are saying that I was wrong to flag this as "not an answer" then why did a moderator mark it as "helpful"?

Comment: Why did you flag it as NAA? Does it not try to answer the question? Downvote bad answers, don't flag them.

Comment: I'm actually surprised it wasn't declined.

Comment: @juergend, yes it's correct. But how the flag got deemed helpful? It should be declined.Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Comment: I know I flagged not for technical wrong, I flagged because this should be comment "Could you try with android:showAsAction="always" android:showAsAction="always" for the items in the menu."

Comment: If it didn't include "Could you try", would you have flagged it? Just curious whether that affected your decision to flag the post.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy ofcourse No because that would have declined I know because I can not flag for technical wrong things there

Comment: @juergend It looks like when it was flagged, the answer said "Could you try with android:showAsAction="always" for the items in the menu." This is a question (no question mark but "Could you try..." makes it a question), and a question should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Downvoter any reason why I got downvote here ?? Any wrong with you guys or with me ?

Comment: Not a duplicate. The cause of this post is that a user's flag was marked as helpful by the community after a review queue pass, but the answer wasn't deleted because of the split nature of the review. That isn't addressed in the other question this is supposedly a duplicate of.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted. This was about clarification, there was nothing to disagree/agree on.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer for more official guidance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the timeline and the review history, here's what happened (BLUF):

- It was not a moderator who marked your flag "helpful", it was an action by the community.

Here's the timeline for that post (Anonymized):

- You flagged it as "not an answer".
- It [went into the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4488264), where it had: 5xRecommend Deletion, and 3x Looks Good, with 1 Edit.
- Your flag was then marked "Helpful" by the community (I'm guessing because it was validated by the above review)

Your flag was marked helpful because it was validated by the community; the post wasn't deleted for reasons I don't fully understand, but I assume it's because there was such a 'split' between the "Looks Good" and "Recommend for Deletion" crowd.

In any case, it is an answer, although not a complete answer.

Comment: Well, upvoted but answer like that "Could you try with android:showAsAction="always" for the items in the menu." can not be answer never, guys should ask this in comment

Comment: @Williams Just because someone's not confident in their answer doesn't mean it isn't an answer.  If the post addresses the question's issue and provides a solution to solve it -- even if the answerer is unsure whether or not it will work, it's an answer.

Comment: If anyone post question related to exception "NullPointerException" and guys start to answer like that can you do this blah then is it answer ?

Comment: Do their posts address the question and provide a possible solution? Then yes.  "Not an answer" flags have a very specific meaning.

Comment: How this could be duplicate of that question as guys did, reason seems different here

Comment: I believe this is overzealous flag handling. When someone chooses Recommend Deletion, the first flag gets marked as helpful, then the next, and the next, until all flags are cleared. But then if the review gets completed as Looks Good anyways, those flags remain cleared as helpful. The Recommend Closure flags work in a similar way.

Comment: @animuson Good to know. I confess I don't know too much about the internals of the flag handling with the review queues.

Comment: Do NAAs currently go to the Low Quality Posts queue?

Comment: This one did because it caught the content and length filter. I think it went into the review queue independently of the user flag.

Comment: @Qantas But to answer your question: Yes, NAA flags do push posts to the LQP queue now.

Answer (score 5):

The post should not be and deleted, and was not deleted.

If you see something like this:

> Could you try this for the `for` loop?
>
> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
>   (function (i) {
>     setTimeout(function () {
>       alert(i);
>     }, 1000);
>   })(i);
> }
> ```

Treat it as though it wasn't asking for someone to try it:

> Your `for` loop should be like this:
>
> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
>   (function (i) {
>     setTimeout(function () {
>       alert(i);
>     }, 1000);
>   })(i);
> }
> ```

Both posts should be treated the same way (except to edit the former post to sound like a definite answer). If the answer as posted is incorrect, downvote it. Otherwise, leave it alone -- don't flag it, even if it's an incorrect answer<sup>1</sup>.

<sub><sup>1:</sup> Though if the question is asking for a Haskell solution and you answer in x86 assembly, that's more of a borderline answer and whether to flag those types of posts is debatable.</sub>