# Repository of useful meta-questions

Tags: feature-request, meta, asking-questions, guidelines

I recently noticed user [gnat](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat) adding very helpful meta-links in comments on Programmers.SE, e.g. in [this typical 'Where to start' question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252945/develop-ios-mobile-chat-with-backend-ror) a link to the
[Where to start? meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start).

These meta posts often apply to more SE sites. Other examples:

- [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6629/how-do-i-explain-something-to-someone/)
- [Gorilla vs Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)
- [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)
- [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)
- [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/on-discussions-and-why-they-dont-make-good-questions?cb=1)

They go deeper than the collection that is e.g. in the sidebar of the different [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages.

I'm bookmarking them so I can use them if necessary, but I assume others also maintain lists like these.

Can we have a repository somewhere where these very useful meta's are collected/available (*meta`d*)? This would serve two purposes:

- Reviewers can pick from these 'guidelines' to quickly 'instruct' an asker about asking good questions
- Question askers could browse this list to get more detailed examples about the kind of questions that are considered 'good' and 'bad'.

Would making *this* question itself the start of such a list (community wiki?) be a good idea?

Comment: We could use [tag:faq] for that, but it can only be applied by moderators.

Comment: @Stijn that seems ok; such a list is only useful if it doesn't become huge, so it'll need to be curated.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I agree, I'm not suggesting that we change it. Just pointing out a potential path and its caveat.

Comment: at Programmers, all references to these are kept under "umbrella" of a single meta post: [Why was my question closed or down voted?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6483/31260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stijn points out in his comment the ideal place would be the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag, but it can only be applied by moderators.

There's no system for this at the moment, but what you could use is the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag to convert the useful question and answer into a proposed FAQ entry. The moderators can then review these and, if they agree, convert the question to CW and replace the tag.

Comment: Those would be per-SE-site FAQs then, right?

Comment: I was thinking you could use this on which ever meta was most appropriate.