# How to manage “I don't have enough reps to comment, so I'll answer”?

Tags: discussion, review

While I'm reviewing posts on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) (but it is not particular to that site), I can see **comments** posted as answers because their author doesn't have enough reputation points to comment.

Is it good to mark "No Action Needed"?

Or better add a comment or flag post as "Not an answer"?

Comment: "No Action Needed"??? Just why?

Comment: I don't have enough reps to downvote you but I'll be sure to with my answer

Comment: Simply remove the comment privilege. Problem solved.

Answer (score 16):

If it's truly not an answer then should be flagged as such.

If the moderator who sees the flag is feeling generous and the "answer" is a good comment they may even convert it to such despite the fact the user doesn't have enough reputation. On Stack Overflow this is rare though.

Comment: @iStimple Well, of course you need to read the whole answer before doing *anything*. I thought that was implied since anything else would be downright unreasonable.

Comment: @iStimple - The assumption (yeah I know) was that the OP was talking about cases where it truly was a comment - but if you're being pedantic....

Answer (score 9):

Just because the phrase

> I don't have enough reps to comment, so I'll answer

or a phrase like that is in the answer, does not mean that it's not an answer.

I've actually ran a query searching for posts that included phrases like that many times before. I can tell you that more than 60% of the time , it is an actual answer, and should not be deleted or flagged as Not An Answer.

So you must read the whole answer. Does it try to answer the question? If so , then just edit out the useless phrase of "not enough rep, so I'll leave an answer" or whatever, and upvote/downvote if you want.

If it really is not an answer, then flag it as Not an Answer, and downvote if you want.

I suggest reading this absolutely brilliant post by Shog on when an answer is and isn't an answer [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Answer (score 1):

LPT: If you're pressing "No Action Needed", you're not working hard enough.

- Edit!

  - Retag
  - Reword the title (for questions)
  - Correct spelling/grammar
  - Formatting
  - Edit code in from a jsfiddle
- Vote!
- Flag/Close (if it's bad)

You should find *something* to do.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't find anything to edit on your answer. I voted if that works for you. ;)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Oh, voting always works for me :)

Comment: The question is about reviewing answers, so title/tags don't really apply.