# An SE site for posting/rating resources, not just questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51

Stack Exchange sites are useful for providing an indication of quality of answers and questions via votes. But what about using the voting system to assess the quality of pre-existing resources? I envision this as working almost like the (admittedly imperfect) system of [peer review](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_review) in academia, but with better incentive structures and transparency.

To put this in context, I'm looking to set-up a site to bring together knowledge on appropriate technology into a single site and was wondering if the SE approach or something similar would be suitable. What we need is some sort of 'peer review' for online 'instructables' type plans and a community forum to ask questions and discuss things. I've set up a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79404/ecotech/79405#79405) in Area 51, I was told about this: "We want to be a knowledge base, not a link directory".

Comment: Related: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: What will the site do to avoid spam? Do check out how [softwarerecs.se] is doing ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is currently [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) in public beta. That seems to be something like what you're envisioning?

There are also [Hardware Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations?referrer=qwrUVaBRsf59It8jRU2FJg2) and [Code (library) Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66606/code-recommendations?referrer=qwrUVaBRsf56TlZ3Al4_Sw2) proposals.

While a dedicated recommendation Q&A site might work (as long as it's specific enough), general recommendation questions don't work so well on most SE sites.

Comment: Note that on Mi Yodeya (Judaism.SE), there is a [product-recommendation](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-recommendation) tag.