# How to determine close and delete reason when super powers were used to dispose of a question or answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I'm looking at a question on Stack Overflow. The question has an answer but the answer was deleted by Stack Overflow (and not the person who answered):

[image]

All that's presented to me is *"comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews"*. There's no reason given for the action.

**Question**: How can I determine why the answer was disposed?

(I tagged this with *Support* because I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong or not using the site correctly. This might need to be a *Feature Request*.)

Comment: What is "Hammer"?

Comment: @Peter - that's the feature where community consensus was abandoned in favor of one person being judge, jury and executioner. I think its called the Mjölnir Hammer. Also see [When did I get close-vote superpowers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589/608639) I changed the title to make it easier to follow (apparently, not everyone is aware of the feature or the name (I fall into the latter group)).

Comment: That is a link only answer. If the link won't work we're left with totally useless answer, hence it's not a fitting answer for Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is that the standard, for them to be deleted with no comment at all? I always use the auto comment...

Comment: @Tim yes, with thousands of flags in the queue and not-so-many moderators, they really better spend their time moderating and not writing comments on each post they delete.

Comment: @Shadow - other options include (1) utilize more moderators, or (2) allow moderators to create a trusted team and delegate work (and require the moderators be responsible for their team if they chose to build a team).

Comment: @jww as for (2) that's already in place: review process, power of 20k users to delete answers with 3 votes and more. When it comes to answer with non-negative score though, only moderator can delete it - the "trusted users" can only point on it marking it as "this isn't good answer, need to delete".

Comment: @Shadow - I *think* the question actually opened a can of worms because it asked us to find an off-site resource. The answer of "RFC 7468" [sic] was quite good, given the question. (But I'm not arguing that. I was simply interested in learning why the answer was deleted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That answer wasn't deleted by "Stack Overflow". It was deleted by a moderator. Why? That's a good question. My *guess* is that it was deleted because it looks like a "link only"/incomplete answer.

Now, that (probably) happens to be a mistake in this particular case, which is fair enough. I don't have any inside knowledge on what prompted the moderator to remove that post. I'm sympathetic to the idea of having a reason listed, but I'm afraid it's not easily done.

On one hand, having a set of predefined reasons would (unfortunately) not work across the network since site policies tend to differ a fair bit. On the other, there may be certain reasons (like "link only") that moderators could use at their discretion... and still create a weirdly inconsistent experience for an average user as they move from site to site.

As it is, the best way to find out the reason for deletion is to ping the moderator in chat or make a meta post and ask for an explanation. (You can also flag the question, but flags aren't really a good avenue for back-and-forth communication.)

Comment: I used *Stack Overflow* to mean "not by the user". Sorry if it caused confusion. But what's the difference? If a moderator is acting on behalf of the site, then isn't that Stack Overflow?

Comment: @jww It is in a way, but we also have a bunch of things in place that could result in an automatic deletion of the answer or an action that's attributed to the Community user under various circumstances... It could be confusing. I prefer to attribute human actions to humans and the rest to robots/Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Anna. Should this be made into a feature request?

Comment: @jww I'm conflicted on that. On one hand, sure. On the other, there are a number of challenges to resolve before it becomes viable (I've mentioned some in my answer). A short & simple "Let's have post deletion reasons." request isn't gonna do it. However, if you have some time to spare to put more thought into this, by all means, don't let me stop you. :)

Comment: Thanks Anna. I'm kinda torn between the loss of community action and the hammer. In my minds eye, the community moving against a question or an answer represents consensus. But an individual wielding the hammer does not enjoy consensus, and they should have to state their reason for cases like this. (I'm a proponent of checks and balances to ensure power is kept in check).

Comment: @jww In most cases, we can infer a reason from an existing flag, but this post wasn't flagged, so I'm not sure what happened here. I pinged the mod in question in chat, so hopefully we get some insight here... although now it's been almost 2 months and I personally can barely remember what happened 2 days ago nevermind 2 months. :) My gut feeling is that this isn't a bit enough problem to build a complex system around, but this wouldn't be the first time I was wrong.

Comment: That post wasn't flagged, but [another one just like it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355046/where-is-the-pem-file-format-specified/28661674#28661674) was, so I arrived at them through the "duplicate answer" filter in the mod queue. They did look like link-only answers, so I deleted them both.

Comment: @BilltheLizard my question was 'is there a standard'. The essential parts of any answer is a) is there is a standard b) what that standard is. Saying 'yes, there is this RFC, here is a link' completely satisfies that. **Internet RFCs are not transient like blog articles.**

Comment: @mikemaccana That doesn't change the facts that: 1. Link-only answers are subject to deletion, no matter where they point to. 2. You shouldn't just copy/paste answers to multiple questions. Use votes to close as duplicate instead. 3. The question itself is probably off-topic for asking for an off-site resource.

Comment: @BilltheLizard 1. The answer was not 'link only' - in the screenshot above you can clearly see that it mentions a) there is a draft RFC b) the name of the draft RFC both of which are relevant answers to my question. 2. The question 'is there a standard for PEM encoding' is separate from 'Where is the PEM file format specified?' since the PEM file format does not include headers as already mentioned in the discussion 3. You're more than welcome to attempt to delete all questions around RFC standards from Stack Overflow. Good luck.