# Dispute a rejected flag

Tags: support, flags

Sorry if this has been asked. I looked and couldn't find the answer I wanted. I marked an answer as not an answer since it did not actually answer the question it was just a repeat of the code. After the flag I commented to the answerer who then did an edit to then actually change his answer into a real answer which was accepted. However someone reviewed my flag and rejected it because it now was a real answer. However that will now show up as a rejected flag to me. Is there no way to just remove it since it was valid before the edit took place?

Or is it one of those cases where I am just going to have to deal with it?

Comment: What you said in the last sentence.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Seems a bit annoying really. That the person who reviewed it did not actually see it before the edits took place. I feel like this is going to be a problem in the future. As I bet without my comment it would of been accepted as not an answer

Comment: Obligatory meta epic on the subject: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not an answer should only be used when the "answer" isn't an attempt at answering the question - so for things like a follow on question, gibberish and such.

If this was an attempt at an answer (however poor or off the mark), it **is** an answer and an attempt to edit it should be made, prior to down voting and flagging with some other flag (low quality, for instance).

Even if the original answer was an incorrect attempt at an answer, it was an answer and the flag would be rejected as such.

So, yes, I guess this is one of those cases where you are just going to have to deal with it...

Comment: It was just a copy of the code that the OP had already. They misunderstood the question. But then when I told them they changed their answer. But I thought it was going to be one of those cases where just have to deal with it

Comment: It might have been an attempt at being the first to answer, followed by editing to an actual answer. Thing is - if it looks like an actual attempt to answer the question, it is an answer.

Comment: So if this is the case. I could just put some code in to start with that slightly resembles an answer so I am the first to answer then edit it to actually finish answering? That seems a bit bad to be honest. But again I am guessing it is one of the things we just have to live with on here

Comment: Shog has a different opinion when it's a link only answer.

Comment: That happens. And that deserves downvotes, certainly. It is better to start with a short answer and edit it into something longer and more in depth, but at least something that is answering the question.

Comment: I suppose yeah. Thank you for helping me understand why it was rejected. I've marked the answer as accepted

Comment: gibberish should be flagged as "abusive"