# Is "trivial answer converted to comment" feature negotiable? Can we opt-in to "I really want my answer to remain an answer"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In [What are current and any publicly announced planned water resistances to the Watch?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198670/what-are-current-and-any-publicly-announced-planned-water-resistances-to-the-wa), I included significant background about water resistance as far as watches go and, by the time I finished my research, realized that elements of my research realized that my base question answered [Waterproof Watch case?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192182/waterproof-watch-case#autocomment237825) significantly better, and more usefully, than the one existing response.

I put an answer to the latter question:

> See the end of my question (in particular, the links) at [What are current and any publicly announced planned water resistances to the Watch?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198670/what-are-current-and-any-publicly-announced-planned-water-resistances-to-the-wa) .

To my surprise, my "trivial answer" was converted to a comment, and when I went to edit it, "edit" meant "edit it as a comment" with no option to convert back to an answer.

My answer was definitely *short*, but it had (by proxy) more and better information than the question's other answer.

Could the present approach be improved, in particular so an answer's character count does not have the last word as to how an answer is received?

Comment: Reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your answer is basically a link to **another question on the same Stack Exchange site**. So you should be doing one of two things:

1. If the other question answers this question:

   You should be voting/flagging to close a duplicate in cases like this.

   By posting a link to another question you are saying:

   > Your answer is over there.

   Why not make it official and close as a duplicate?
2. If the other question is just related:

   Leave a comment pointing to the other question as your "answer" does not answer the current question.

Comment: Except that the questions aren't duplicates in my eyes. One is asking about future water-resistance and the other is asking about current water resistance and specifically looking for a third-party case... plus, the OP asked the linked question significantly **after** the "duplicate" question.

Comment: @Catija the order the questions were asked makes no difference. If the newer question has better answers then the older question should be the one closed. Plus if the answer to one question **is a link to the other** then it *has* to be a duplicate.

Comment: The new question is asking about **Apple** solutions and the older question is asking about if a specific **third party** product is good and what can be expected of it. They're completely different questions.

Comment: @Catija - My answer is to the general point of "can we turn off this feature". I really don't want to get into discussing the specific question, but either way the "answer" isn't an answer. It's either a vote to close as duplicate or, if what you say is true a comment because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's all I'm trying to say. It's a comment because it doesn't answer the question... but that's not anywhere in your answer.

Comment: @Catija - well from the question as asked here that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 8):

Your answer was likely converted to a comment because it does not **in any way** answer the question.

The question is specifically asking about a third-party (non-Apple) case for the Apple Watch and how good it is - and if there are better water-resistance options.

[Waterproof Watch case?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192182/waterproof-watch-case#autocomment237825)

> Assuming I use this case, about how far under water can I go if at all? And is there a better option?

Your links to articles are both about a naked Apple Watch without a case at all while the question is asking for information about cases.

Though the information that the watch is somewhat water-resistant is certainly helpful to the OP, it's not an **answer**, it is information best included as a comment.

The other option would be to actually flesh out the answer to say something like:

> "Even without the case, the Apple watch has pretty good water resistance for things like showers and even swimming and diving. Here are some articles and here are quotes of particularly useful sections of the articles."

That would be an answer... redirecting someone to your own question - [or to any link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) - is not an answer without including some real content & context.

Answer (score 4):

> My answer was definitely short, but it had (by proxy) more and better
>   information than the question's other answer.

Someone else's answer being *poor* does not stop another answer being also *poor*, nor even 10 other answers being poor.

Don't judge your answers based on other people's answers, judge it based on it's own merits.
If someone posts a really crap answer, I don't just aim slightly better than their answer. Also, they might improve their answer, and then yours is the poor*est* answer.

> Could the present approach be improved, in particular so an answer's
>   character count does not have the last word as to how an answer is
>   received?

The present approach is designed to counter poor quality answers being posted, such as your example answer (sorry, no offence intended, but it is low quality and should be a comment).

I'm glad the site recognises such things, and avoids it *all* being shoved through the review queues, as your example answer would most certainly have been flagged, and also quite likely moved to a comment by reviewers (myself included if I came across the review).

In this case, the site system was correct.
If at some point in the future you post a genuine answer which gets converted to a comment, do consider that it's a rare occurrence, and resolving the issue of *many* poor answers outweighs the few times when someone just needs to simply pad out their answer a bit.

It's happened to me, my small sentence was a very valid answer, but converted to a comment.
I simply *grrrd* a bit, copy/pasted it back into an answer, padded it out, and deleted the comment.
No harm done. In fact, arguably, I made the answer a bit better with more info ;)