# "How to not be a spammer" help page contains badly-rendered HTTP link on all sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, ssl

See the image below. The link to the Meta post is not in HTTPS on all sites (including SO, SU, SF, AU), at this page:

```
https://*.stackexchange.com/help/promotion
```

[image]

As I tweaked in the F12 Developer Console, this should be the correct look:

[image]

With the correct link which will hopefully make the Markdown renderer fetch the title of the post automatically:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer
```

Comment: @animuson A side question: Shall we batch-replace links in help  center to HTTPS? There are still a lot of other HTTP links. I canlt find a single link that does not support HTTPS so it's fine to replace.

Comment: A related post about Help Center in general: [Help has non-HTTPS links in it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327823)