# Help Center pages contain non-HTTPS links

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, ssl

Pages within the [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) have many non-HTTPS links on them.

Many of the ones to questions seem to have been updated, but there are non-HTTPS links to the Stack Overflow blog on [Don't Ask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), links to Area 51 and the main domain of stackexchange.com on [On-Topic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), a link to a Main Meta on [Closed Questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), a link to the Stack Overflow blog on [Duplicates](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) and presumably more of the help. The [moderator tools help](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) has a lot of non-HTTPS links, along with some HTTPS links.

These were tested on the [Meta help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help), too, and the links that are on both I confirmed to be non-HTTPS.

Comment: Not sure if this has been updated since the bounty was placed but I failed to find any non-SSL `http://` in the linked pages.

Comment: @bad_coder On the few sites I tried (including [scifi.se] - which is the one in the post), `help/dont-ask` contains http links here: 
"For more detail, read about our [guidelines for great subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and blog post about how [real questions have answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)."

Comment: [SEDE only contains a few help-center items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378446), so there isn't a way to check all of them using SEDE. But perhaps developers have some way to find *all* http links without manually checking each part

Comment: @Martin ok, [caught it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) the argument is sometimes made that if the protocol isn't specified in the URL (not `https` nor `http`) the browser will try to resolve to `https` first but I still think [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_You_See_Is_What_You_Get_(disambiguation)) is a better policy in that regard since the user isn't left wondering about what they're getting.

Answer (score 9):

For the `/help/on-topic` page, for which the site's ♦ moderators are responsible, I threw together a quick userscript to detect non-HTTPS links network-wide. When you run it on https://stackexchange.com/sites, it will run through all sites and dump a list of links.

The page template ([example from a new beta site](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) contains a few non-HTTPS links:

- `http://area51.stackexchange.com/`
- `http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq`
- `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site` (for older sites, `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site`)
- `http://stackexchange.com/sites` (older sites only)

so those are filtered out. I hope staff is willing to adjust the template so that new sites won't have this problem. I'm off to update the links on 'my' sites...

#### Results

```
https://ai.stackexchange.com:
http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Ant_colony_optimization

https://korean.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-is-the-policy-for-translation-requests
http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/151/should-we-change-our-off-topic-rules-to-allow-small-translations
http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/118/general-reference-questions
http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/55/how-much-of-korean-culture-questions-should-be-allowed-here
http://korean.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
http://korean.stackexchange.com/tags

https://crafts.stackexchange.com:
http://photo.stackexchange.com/
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/
http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/

https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/

https://latin.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/143/12

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/

https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com:
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/
http://meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com/
http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help

https://es.stackoverflow.com:
http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates
http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions
http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/67/are-questions-about-api-specific-stuff-on-topic
http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-about-debugging-opengl-shaders-on-topic
http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/67/are-questions-about-api-specific-stuff-on-topic
http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/146/are-questions-asking-for-off-site-resources-on-topic
http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/141/are-questions-about-software-recommendation-in-scope
http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information
http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-asking-about-maya-or-3ds-max-blender-api-on-topic
http://superuser.com
http://blender.stackexchange.com
http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/176/is-computer-vision-in-scope
http://dsp.stackexchange.com

https://portuguese.stackexchange.com:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com
http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/

https://opensource.stackexchange.com:
http://superuser.com/help/on-topic
http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://law.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/221/58
http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/261/10
http://law.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

https://rus.stackexchange.com:
http://rus.stackexchange.com/search
http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46568/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23242/
http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/a/168/178412

https://ru.stackoverflow.com:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators
http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

https://musicfans.stackexchange.com:
http://music.stackexchange.com
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21415/off-the-record
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

https://engineering.stackexchange.com:
http://engineering.stackexchange.com/search
http://engineering.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer
http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/368
http://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/335/368
http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/368
http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope
http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

https://economics.stackexchange.com:
http://imgur.com/

https://hsm.stackexchange.com:
http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/58/what-motivated-cantor-to-invent-set-theory
http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-about-mathematicians-and-scientists-lives-on-topic
http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/727/who-discovered-smooth-non-analytic-functions-of-a-real-variable
http://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism
http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2784/20
http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1675
http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolved-mysteries
http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3142/list-examples-of-things-you-think-are-on-topic-or-off-topic
http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags
http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1650/challenge-questions-and-post-quality-how-should-we-proceed/1651#1651
http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5880/what-are-the-features-of-a-well-written-puzzle
http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/
http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search
http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com:
http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search
http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer
http://physics.stackexchange.com/
http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

https://expatriates.stackexchange.com:
http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
http://travel.stackexchange.com/
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13567/the-embassy
http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/
http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer
http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information
http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software
http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality

https://ebooks.stackexchange.com:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/

https://aviation.stackexchange.com:
http://travel.stackexchange.com
http://space.stackexchange.com

https://pt.stackoverflow.com:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

https://italian.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/31/are-questions-about-dialects-on-topic
http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-translation-requests-on-topic
http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/21/should-we-admit-easily-answerable-questions
http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-good-reference-works-on-italian-are-available-online

https://ham.stackexchange.com:
http://www.fcc.gov/encyclopedia/general-mobile-radio-service-gmrs
http://meta.ham.stackexchange.com/questions/186/should-questions-on-broadcast-radio-be-specifically-off-topic

https://pets.stackexchange.com:
http://pets.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/798/should-medical-emergencies-always-be-off-topic
http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions
http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com:
http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/
http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search

https://sound.stackexchange.com:
http://music.stackexchange.com
http://video.stackexchange.com/

https://mathoverflow.net:
http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/

https://blender.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6
http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://freelancing.stackexchange.com:
http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal
http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/55/should-this-site-have-a-back-it-up-rule

https://opendata.stackexchange.com:
http://opendefinition.org/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://tridion.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://magento.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://politics.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/40/should-we-have-a-back-it-up-rule-for-answers?rq=1
http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/politics-vs-economics?cb=1
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com:
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://stackexchange.com

https://robotics.stackexchange.com:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/
http://electronics.stackexchange.com
http://stackoverflow.com
http://scifi.stackexchange.com
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6221
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://genealogy.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/on-and-off-topic-questions-what-is-genealogy-and-family-history
http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/
http://history.stackexchange.com/
http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://patents.stackexchange.com:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/
http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com
http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/

https://islam.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://russian.stackexchange.com:
http://russian.stackexchange.com/search
http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/833/71
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/
http://unix.stackexchange.com
http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
http://www.stackoverflow.com

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142/22
http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://workplace.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694
http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice
http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696
http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695
http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2596
http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for
http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler
http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges
http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://academia.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/1203
http://stackexchange.com/sites
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974

https://sports.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/332
http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/266
http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/289
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/the-clubhouse/
http://fitness.stackexchange.com
http://outdoors.stackexchange.com
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://martialarts.stackexchange.com:
http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/search/
http://fitness.stackexchange.com/
http://movies.stackexchange.com/
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/
http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope
http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/
http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/search
http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer
http://stackexchange.com/sites
http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://psychology.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com:
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help
http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://poker.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://biology.stackexchange.com:
http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://chinese.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/q/237/43
http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources
http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1120/43
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1984/chinese-language-and-usage
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://movies.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites
http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/538/you-can-select-tags-to-ignore

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/338/can-scicomp-stackexchange-be-used-for-project-specific-questions
http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/341/add-software-authorship-disclosures-to-our-badges
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://math.stackexchange.com
http://physics.stackexchange.com/
http://stats.stackexchange.com/
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://history.stackexchange.com:
http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/writing/history/critical/historiography.html
http://genealogy.stackexchange.com
http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com:
http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer
http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/533/43
http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/207/a-new-guideline-for-doctrine-in-questions-what-do-you-think
http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=votes
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://linguistics.stackexchange.com:
http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/about
http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/331/111
http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/11/111
http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/529/111
http://stackexchange.com/sites
http://stackexchange.com/sites
http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/344/111
http://chat.stackexchange.com/
http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://christianity.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1487
http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth
http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/777
http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/816
http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/132
http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/193
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/christianity
http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/614
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://dsp.stackexchange.com:
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/69/15892
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/646/what-is-the-most-lucid-intuitive-explanation-for-the-various-fts-cft-dft-dt
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16394/removing-baseline-drift-from-ecg-signal
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/374/15892
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/vehicle-counting-from-a-video
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74/what-factors-should-i-consider-in-choosing-an-edge-detection-algorithm
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30506/basic-fir-filtering-with-audio-buffer-in-c
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11008/intuitive-interpretation-of-laplace-transform
http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/i-also-think-that-this-question-should-not-have-been-migrated-away-from-dsp-se
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://travel.stackexchange.com:
http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://gardening.stackexchange.com:
http://cooking.stackexchange.com
http://biology.stackexchange.com
http://diy.stackexchange.com
http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com:
http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-does-nietzsche-define-and-characterize-freedom-throughout-his-works
http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70/could-cogito-ergo-sum-possibly-be-false
http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://japanese.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/806
http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/982/1478
http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/796
http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/797
http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756
http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/798/29
http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/799/29
http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/761#761
http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1463/1478
http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/800/
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://german.stackexchange.com:
http://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628
http://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1057/2594
http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1057/2594
http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/628
http://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/919
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://judaism.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473
http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48/cylor-disclaimer
http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi
http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/123/how-modest-should-this-site-be/125#comment-206
http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75/excerpting-articles/76#76

https://sqa.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-scope
http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/326/what-do-we-want-to-do-about-how-do-i-program-questions
http://stackoverflow.com/search
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://music.stackexchange.com:
http://law.stackexchange.com/
http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/
http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://parenting.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites
http://fitness.stackexchange.com
http://superuser.com
http://money.stackexchange.com
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://mechanics.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://drupal.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://fitness.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5
http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users
http://biology.stackexchange.com
http://chemistry.stackexchange.com
http://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com
http://physics.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://pm.stackexchange.com:
http://workplace.stackexchange.com
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/
http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://quant.stackexchange.com:
http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/141
http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/306
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://stats.stackexchange.com/
http://money.stackexchange.com/

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1511
http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info
http://stackoverflow.com
http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questions
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://dba.stackexchange.com:
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-ms-access-on-topic
http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=votes&pagesize=15
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com:
http://www.superuser.com/help/on-topic

https://video.stackexchange.com:
http://sound.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://security.stackexchange.com:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://physics.stackexchange.com:
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/629
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25324
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2051
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3096
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88799/numerical-simulation-of-sound-propagation-in-air
http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange
http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site/4539#4539
http://scifi.stackexchange.com
http://scicomp.stackexchange.com
http://stackoverflow.com
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://electronics.stackexchange.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-off-topic
http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference
http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index
http://stackexchange.com

https://rpg.stackexchange.com:
http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons
http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs-in-the-vineyard
http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowrun-sr4
http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness
http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/
http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/
http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go
http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com:
http://www.acm.org
http://www.sigact.org/
http://cs.stackexchange.com/
http://math.stackexchange.com/
http://mathoverflow.net/
http://academia.stackexchange.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://stats.stackexchange.com/
http://crypto.stackexchange.com/
http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/
http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask
http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question
http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/126/
http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/229#229
http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science
http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/237#237
http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/235#235
http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/361#361
http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/231#231
http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/274/is-it-ok-to-ask-about-the-correctness-of-preprints-on-crank-friendly-topics/281#281
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://unix.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/97/29
http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/314/29
http://askubuntu.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2642/
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073
http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://ux.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/how-do-i-add-mockups-and-or-visuals-to-my-questions
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/
http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/629/is-it-time-to-put-an-end-to-icon-for-x-questions
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14571/how-do-you-create-or-select-an-icon-for-a-feature
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://askubuntu.com:
http://www.ubuntu.com
http://community.ubuntu.com/
http://askubuntu.com
http://developer.ubuntu.com
http://design.ubuntu.com
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification
http://insights.ubuntu.com/
http://shop.ubuntu.com
http://apps.ubuntu.com
http://ubuntuforums.org
http://www.launchpad.net
http://maas.ubuntu.com
http://www.canonical.com
http://askubuntu.com/faq#etiquette
http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives
http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask
http://unix.stackexchange.com/
http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/226/are-bug-reports-suitable-for-this-site
http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug
http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/871/41
http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do
http://askubuntu.com/help/tagging
http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/faq
http://meta.askubuntu.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://tex.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx
http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://gis.stackexchange.com:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/3349
http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401/other-places-for-help
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://diy.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/607/can-we-discourage-shop-for-me-type-questions
http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1012/should-questions-about-smells-be-off-topic
http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/
http://gardening.stackexchange.com/
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://math.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/8348
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com
http://mathoverflow.net
http://stats.stackexchange.com
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com
http://scicomp.stackexchange.com
http://stackoverflow.com
http://cs.stackexchange.com
http://dsp.stackexchange.com
http://matheducators.stackexchange.com
http://hsm.stackexchange.com
http://physics.stackexchange.com
http://electronics.stackexchange.com
http://quant.stackexchange.com
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-should-go-in-the-math-stackexchange-faq/117#117
http://tex.stackexchange.com
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://stats.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated
http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/how-should-questions-be-answered-on-cross-validated
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812
http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/12/919
http://stackoverflow.com
http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software
http://math.stackexchange.com
http://gis.stackexchange.com
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://photo.stackexchange.com:
http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/can-we-re-open-the-door-to-something-a-little-like-photo-critique
http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/150/should-photo-critiques-be-allowed
http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/can-we-re-open-the-door-to-something-a-little-like-photo-critique
http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130/should-we-allow-questions-about-unreleased-cameras
http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/28/can-i-ask-videography-related-questions
http://stackexchange.com/sites/
http://video.stackexchange.com/
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/
http://superuser.com/
http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://cooking.stackexchange.com:
http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/
http://gardening.stackexchange.com
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info
http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/search
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com:
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://serverfault.com/
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/
http://superuser.com/
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catch-all
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://gaming.stackexchange.com:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://webapps.stackexchange.com:
http://android.stackexchange.com/
http://apple.stackexchange.com/
http://superuser.com
http://stackoverflow.com
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/
http://stackexchange.com/sites

https://superuser.com:
http://stackexchange.com/sites
http://meta.superuser.com/questions/855/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions
http://meta.superuser.com

https://serverfault.com:
http://blog.serverfault.com?blb=1
```

#### Script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Help Center analyzer
// @author      Glorfindel
// @version     0.1
// @match       https://stackexchange.com/sites
// @connect     stackexchange.com
// @connect     *.stackexchange.com
// @connect     *.stackoverflow.com
// @connect     *.superuser.com
// @connect     *.serverfault.com
// @connect     *.askubuntu.com
// @connect     *.mathoverflow.net
// @connect     stackapps.com
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant       GM.xmlHttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

/* global $ */

(function() {
  'use strict';

  var sites = [];
  $("div.lv-item > a").each(function() {
    sites.push($(this).attr("href"));
  });
  
  var message = "";  
  function process() {
    let URL = sites.pop();
    if (typeof URL == 'undefined') {
      console.log(message);
      return;
    }
    
    let helpURL = URL + "/help/on-topic";
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      url: helpURL,
      onload: function(data) {
        var first = true;
        $(data.responseText).find("a[href^='http://']").each(function() {
          let link = this.getAttribute("href");
          if (link == "http://area51.stackexchange.com/" || link == "http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq" ||
              link == "http://stackexchange.com/sites" ||
              link == "http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site" ||
              link == "http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site")
            return;
          if (first) {
            first = false;
            message += "\n\n" + URL + ":"; 
          }
          message += "\n" + link;
        });
        process();
      }
    });
  };
  process();
})();
```

Comment: Just to clarify - these are only the links in this one page on `/help/on-topic` (for each site), right? There still might be http links in many other pages in the help center. Such as [the `/help/dont-ask` page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which was mentioned by the OP as an example.

Comment: @Martin yes, but those need to be updated once, by staff on Meta.SE.

Comment: Can you scan for `https://meta.*.stackexchange.com` too, since that gives cert errors? (Also I'm laughing because I updated the ELU Help Center two days ago to fix problems like these.)

Comment: @Laurel no hits, fortunately

Comment: So still lots of non-HTTPS links out there, that only site mods can change?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard yes. The [tag:status-completed] is a bit misleading, since that's only about the parts staff can/will do.

Answer (score 8):

I updated the help pages linked here and replaced all occurrences of `http://` with `https://` that I could find.

**Update**: I have updated 26 help page templates to make this change. This should take care of all updates on the network-level. Any help pages that are out there with `http://` links should now just be on site-customizations (please go to the mods on the relevant site directly for fixing those).

> so many links need
> manual updating now
> it is quite irksome

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to have had some [side effects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378676/295232) ...

Comment: In case it might be useful for others, here is a link to [a related conversation on chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1632/conversation/http-https-links-in-the-help-center). (Although probably it doesn't contain something *extremely* important.)

Comment: Have those changes been reversed somehow? e.g. https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Glorfindel it's fine on other sites e.g. [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so it means the template did not affect all sites. Do note Yaakov said "This **should** take care of all updates on the network-level", note the bold part. Anyway, you can safely remove the [tag:status-completed] tag, the reported problems are not resolved.

Comment: That page on outdoors hasnt been updated since 2018 and was missed in the first round. I just fixed it.