# Markdown rendering anomaly in the Help Center on SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, help-center

On Stack Overflow the [privileges for a trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) page in the Help Center currently shows the following minor rendering anomaly:

> ##Deleting answers ###When should I vote to delete an answer?

As you can see, the hash symbols (`#`), presumably in the Markdown, are not being converted to `<h2>` and `<h3>` tags. I think that the Markdown is just missing a space character before each word; "*Deleting*" and "*When*".

Expected rendering:

> ### Deleting answers
>
> #### When should I vote to delete an answer?

Comment: Blame [@Yaakov](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378666/295232) ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Formatting has been updated. I scanned through some of the other articles edited yesterday to see if there was any other broken formatting that never got updated and didn't see anything, but obviously easy to miss. Let us know if you see broken stuff anywhere else.