# Questions about repositories & off-site resources

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

This is about questions like this question of mine - *[Older Versions of JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098129/older-versions-of-jax-ws)*

I understand why Stack Overflow wouldn't like to have questions like these. However, I couldn't find any other SE site where such questions would be topical. Is there one? If not, is there any interest in creating one?

Answer (score 3):

Answers to these questions are always going to consist of lists of links to where the resources can be found at the moment of answering. As such they are always at the mercy of the sites they point to reorganising or going down.

In the end they are just a [search snapshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), something that's better done by the person needing the information at the time they need it. No Stack Exchange site offers this because it's not useful recording what a search engine returned at some point in the past.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with questions, or even answers like that is they don't stand the test of time. If they stop hosting those older versions - (and really who's going to host all the things in perpetuity?) the answer(s) have completely lost their value. In a sense, its the same issues we have for software recommendation type questions on SU.

In a sense, the best folks to ask are the folks who're hosting it, or... actually update to a supported version of the library