# Unable to close question because of "answer converted to comment"

Tags: support, accepted-answer, cross-posting

I posted a question on Stack Overflow:
[Postgres: Why did adding index slow down regexp queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505822/postgres-why-did-adding-index-slow-down-regexp-queries)

Because of lack of reactions, I later posted the same question on DBA Stack Exchange:
[Postgres: why did this trigram index slow down regexp queries?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240122/postgres-why-did-this-trigram-index-slow-down-regexp-queries)

It got answered on DBA, and I accepted the answer there.

---

*Problem:*
Now I cannot delete my SO question, because "others have already invested time and effort" (there's one answer already, though not terribly relevant).

I cannot close it as a duplicate either, because that would require a link within SO (not to DBA).

I cannot provide and accept the correct answer either: I tried posting an answer on SO linking to DBA with a short explanation, so I could accept that. But no luck either, I'm getting some "your answer was trivial so we automatically converted it to a comment" nonsense.

Any other ideas how to close the question, providing the correct answer?

Comment: Why have you tagged this as a bug? The question has an answer with an upvote—so you shouldn't be able to delete it. Nor, as you state, should it be a duplicate of something at a different site. And if your "answer" was so trivial that it was converted to a comment, that seems appropriate too. I don't see how this is a bug in any way—the system is doing what it should be doing. What are you actually asking?

Comment: I'm asking how to provide the correct answer on SO and accept it, thus closing the question and informing others of the correct solution. See the question title above, I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: @user124114 You can always quote and cite the other answer in addition to simply linking to it.

Comment: @AnneDaunted Feel free to write a long answer, I'll accept it. I have no idea what the criteria for "trivial answer" are (one sentence explanation wasn't enough, I tried). Nor am I inclined to investigate and make up some fake verbiage just to appease some algo.

Comment: @JasonBassford that would be one way, but sounds wrong: the "real" DBA answer was not done by me, and contains additional useful discussion and comments.

Comment: @user124114 Why does that sound wrong?

Comment: @DavidZ see the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @user124114 Sorry I wasn't clear. What I meant to ask is, why would the facts that the answer wasn't written by you and that it has comments present any obstacle to you quoting and citing it as Jason suggested? (I ask since, as you know now, that _is_ the right way to do it, and I'm curious to understand the logic behind your objection.)

Comment: @DavidZ I'm a programmer, opposed to inferior copy-pasting of answers that would lack context and violate DRY (the same answer in two places, out of sync). Doesn't it feel wrong to you? DBA is the superior site here, they ended up providing the authoritative solution.

Comment: @user124114 No, it definitely does not feel wrong to me. This is more like a versioned release than code reuse; the whole point is to maintain a snapshot of the (relevant portion of the) source as it existed when it was quoted, by explicitly making sure that the two places do _not_ automatically stay in sync if the original is updated.

Answer (score 11):

Short answers containing links are automatically converted to comments [because they are not answers by Stack Exchange's commonly accepted definition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/295232).

In case you find an answer to your question elsewhere (whether it is on another Stack Exchange, Reddit, Quora, Wikipedia – it doesn't really matter, as long as the license of the content allows it), there are two correct ways to proceed:

1. ask the author of the post via a comment to post their answer on Stack Overflow as well
2. copy the answer and properly cite it, [like I just did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56716404/4751173). Preserving the markup can be a bit tricky, especially if code blocks are involved. But you can see it works. If you feel you don't deserve the reputation from upvotes the copied answer might get, make it a Community Wiki post.

Incidentally, this situation is one of the reasons cross posting is disliked on Stack Exchange.