# Should I re-answer a migrated question if my original answer is gone?

Tags: discussion, answers, migration

[A question I'd answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597527/fails-at-fixing-unmet-dependencies) got migrated to another site, and for some reason my answer seems to have gotten deleted in the process. Should I answer the question again on the new site? I don't know if it was the right answer or not; I'm not sure if the person who asked the question even saw it since the question was migrated shortly afterwards. If my answer was intentionally deleted for being a bad answer than I probably shouldn't re-post it, but as far as I know that's not the case. The answer did link to another answer on the same site; would that have anything to do with it being deleted and/or change whether I should re-post it or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the FAQ: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/295232)

> Migration allows an off-topic question to be gracefully moved to another site in the Stack Exchange network. It preserves the current revision of the question, *all its answers*, any comments on any post, as well as most of the votes.

> Answers on the origin site are deleted immediately upon question migration. (This causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site.) *The answers will be visible on the destination question.*

(emphasis mine)

What exactly happened here, I don't know (perhaps the moderators or the  can tell), but it's safe to say that when answers are normally migrated along their parent question, it's absolutely fine to post the answer again on the target site.

If your answer *only* consisted of a link to another answer, it might have been deleted as being a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/295232) but usually a comment is left on those indicating *why* they were deleted.

Comment: My answer was mostly a link, so that's possible. As far as I know there were no comments but my answer seems to have disappeared without a trace so maybe there was a comment and it disappeared too? Anyway, I'll try to improve my answer so it's more than a link this time.

Comment: That's certainly a good idea!

Comment: Even if it was deleted.  Unless the question got deleted.  The author of the answer should be able to see it.  Based on the answer that has now been submitted, if that's the same answer, it was deleted due to the low quality of the answer.