# Escaped "\n" in failed-review audit-warning

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

I was reviewing the [First posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) queue today for the first time.  I've so far passed the few audits that have come my way.  I marked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/29520400) as **No action needed**, though it was only a link, but since the votes were low (or *so it seemed*) and the answer itself didn't seem like spam, I marked it as ok.

However, I was deceived. :)

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You didn't pass.** This post was of very poor quality, and needed significant improvements to be useful – passing over such posts hurts the ability of others to find and answer good questions. \nPlease try to fix such posts by editing, downvoting, closing, or flagging as "very low quality".
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

Notice the "\n" in "**\n**Please try to fix such posts..."

Comment: For the record, the post you marked is basically a link-only answer. Such answers are [NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/269301).