# Does it matter if a post discloses the author's affiliation if it only exists to promote a product or service?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

The definition of the spam flag is:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

And it links to the site's `/help/promotion` page. Based on the tips provided for not being a spammer, it seems like you would still be a spammer if you regularly and overtly promote your product or service, regardless of disclosure. Failure to include relevant information in the answer itself also [makes the post not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Flagging posts as spam come with automatic penalties related to reputation loss and spam blocking algorithms. This can be seen as a good thing. However, the guidance seems to suggest treating such posts as you would posts that aren't an answer with down votes and/or votes for deletion without the penalties that come with spam.

Is there any reason to treat a post that does not stand alone to directly answer the question and points to the poster's product or service as spam, even if the affiliation is disclosed in the post? I can't think of one, but the guidance on the flagging page suggests otherwise.

Comment: I VTC'd towards the FAQ as, IMO, the guidance we have there is pretty clear on that part: being attributed doesn't exempt something from being unsolicited. Freely flag as spam.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine No. I'm asking _why_ that guidance is what it is and if it still makes sense. That link doesn't answer my question. The guidance seems to indicate a preference toward treating posts as low quality or not an answer rather than spam, which doesn't make sense. It's quite clear that as soon as you include attribution, you shouldn't flag it as spam, as implied by the flag description and explicit in the Meta SE post you linked to. However, that guidance is years old at this point.

Comment: So you're asking about cases where someone posts "Low price limo service New York [link]. Best prices, superior service with Big Apple Limo. Disclosure: I work for Big Apple Limo." as an answer to a programming question and whether that is spam or simply NAA?

Comment: @RobertColumbia No. Consider if someone posted "I wrote an open-source library that solves this problem. Check it out on GitHub." It's both solicited (technically answers the question) and attributed (the post makes it clear the poster is the author of the library). By the current definition, it would not be spam. At most, it would be "not an answer", down voted, and perhaps voted for deletion. It would not trigger the -100 reputation for spam or feed into the anti-spam measures that exist. I'm not convinced this is correct.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I am not sure I get what's unclear about the policy we have: "A post should be marked as spam only if it promotes a product, service, or similar; and is unsolicited **or** lacks disclosure of affiliation."... Whatever the probably ambiguous wording of the company may suggest, it bears no weight in community curation unless it directly contradicts it. After all, moderators are community representatives, not the company's. An unsolicited disclosed post is spam, there is no other interpretation of it I can think of. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] If a post directly answers the question, and is not NAA (i.e., is not a link to the service / whatever), it likely shouldn't be flagged as spam (unless you notice a pattern of the user posting such answers too much). Otherwise, it is blatant spam, no two ways about it. Speaking of your last example, it does seem like it qualifies for just being an NAA "link-only" if it directly addresses the question.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine It's not that the policy is unclear. It's quite clear. I'm asking _why_ the policy is what it is and _if_ we should reconsider that policy. I'm beginning to think that posts that exist only to promote products or services and don't stand on their own to answer the question should be treated as spam. I can't find any rationale for why the policy is what it is, only that it is what it is.

Answer (score 10):

I think the general view I have is "disclosure is necessary but not sufficient"

At the single question level - I'd say a *tailored* answer showing how to use a product to *specifically* answer a question is fine. Such answers are *not* basically regurgitating ad copy, but rather using subject matter expertise to *show* how to solve the issue with specific tools you'd be familiar with due to your affiliation.

However...

At an *account* level ideally the user's contributions shouldn't be focused *entirely* (or very substantially) on promoting the product. The text for the moderator message for spam - is *titled* "excessive self promotion" starts "We noticed that some of your posts seem to exist only to promote your product or website.", which reflects this.

Comment: I'd agree that a tailored answer that shows how to use a product is allowed. However, what about just a one-off (or two-off or something that is not excessive) pointer to a product, service, website, etc.? Effectively, an answer that is "I wrote a tool to solve this problem - check it out on GitHub". The current guidance is to treat it as not an answer rather than spam. Does that make sense and, if so, why?

Comment: Also, the _why_ aspect is what I'm really getting at. I've been noticing a trend where people will post answers with links that answer the question, whether it's a tool on GitHub or a blog post on another site, without giving sufficient detail to answer the question in a stand-alone form. It seems like the anti-spam measures would be appropriate for these, but there may be good reasons why it's not.

Comment: Well - that's one of the reasons I'd take a look at both the singular question and the aggregate is - it makes sense to treat *one* as not an answer and advice the user, but if the user has a bunch, we have other issues

Comment: So specifically - I'd go with user education and nudging them to do 'better' answers *before* the spam-hammer in such cases

Comment: It's more about a trend across users, though. I guess I'm not convinced that nudging is worth the time, especially since it doesn't scale. Bringing out the spam-hammer fast is good. If a user goes to meta to ask, then that's a good opportunity for education and helping, since the only real loss is reputation points for registered accounts.

Comment: @ThomasOwens "Effectively, an answer that is "I wrote a tool to solve this problem - check it out on GitHub"" That's a link-only answer. If it's only once or twice, I'd go [with NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/269301). Spam flags are too heavy-handed for that. Even if it starts becoming obvious (say, 6 posts in succession but not within a spammy timeframe), most moderators prefer a mod-flag pointing out the behaviour instead of a wave of redflags. Some users don't realize what they do is wrong. That is, assuming the content is relevant. If it's not, or barely, it's just spam.

Comment: @Mast Still, I don't get _why_ going with NAA is the preferred or accepted route and _why_ spam flags would be considered too heavy handed. I think a spam flag is very much appropriate, but everything disagrees with me. What is the rationale behind that? Is this something that we should reconsider?

Comment: The whole assume good intent really. That we can *teach* someone who doesn't know better to know better.